# Make layer from layer mask

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

I want to create layer from layer mask, like in this gif:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1ncB.gif]

And i need to do this from script. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Script or action?

The action steps are:

- Select the mask
- Make a Solid Color layer
- Rasterize Layer
- Apply Layer Mask

[image: Action]

Comment: Yes i want to do that by script - exactly what you showed in gif, but in photoshop-scripting

Answer (score 0):

Record an action for it.

In the Actions panel, click the Create New Action button , or choose New Action from the Actions panel menu. Enter an action name, select an action set, and set additional options: ...
Click Begin Recording. ...
Perform the operations and commands you want to record.